# Azure table storage REST Query doesn't show new entries

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-table-storage, azure-rest-api

I'm building a query for a Azure Storage Account(tables in this case). I try to receive the last log entries of the last day.

The filter looks like this in the storage query builder:

```
{
  "filter": [
    {
      "id": "{ID}",
      "andOr": "And",
      "field": "TIMESTAMP",
      "type": "DateTime",
      "operator": ">=",
      "value": "datetime'2019-11-18T10:08:41.296Z'",
      "timeValue": "Last 24 hours",
      "timestampType": "time",
      "customTimestamp": {
        "lastNumber": 7,
        "lastTimeUnit": "Days"
      },
      "isLocal": true
    }
  ],
  "select": null,
  "group": {
    "id": "{ID}",
    "children": [
      "{CHILD}"
    ]
  },
  "top": null,
  "filterType": "Query Builder",
  "fileVersion": 0.2
}
```

This query returnes all the entries from the last day.
I tried to use this filter in the Azure REST API call. in a powershell function like this:

```
function GetTableEntityAll($TableName) {
    $version = "2017-04-17"
    $resource = "$tableName()" 
    $DST =  [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1)
    $table_url = "https://$storageAccount.table.core.windows.net/$resource"+ '?$filter=Timestamp gt datetime' + "'"+ $DST.ToString("s") + "'"
write-host $table_url
    $GMTTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().toString('R')
    $stringToSign = "$GMTTime`n/$storageAccount/$resource"
    $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
    $hmacsha.key = [Convert]::FromBase64String($accesskey)
    $signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($stringToSign))
    $signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)
    $headers = @{
        'x-ms-date'    = $GMTTime
        Authorization  = "SharedKeyLite " + $storageAccount + ":" + $signature
        "x-ms-version" = $version
        Accept         = "application/json;odata=fullmetadata"
    }
    $item = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $table_url -Headers $headers -ContentType application/json
    return $item.value
}
```

The URL I generate with this is:

```
https://{Accountname}.table.core.windows.net/{Tablename}()?$filter=Timestamp gt datetime'2019-11-18T00:00:00'
```

This doesn't return any records. I also tried to encode the url but that doesns't work either. If I change the datetime to 2016 I receive the first few records.

Azure documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities

Any ideas?

Comment: Please check the response headers. Do you see headers like next PartitionKey and/or next RowKey?

Comment: There are no response headers inside $item

Comment: @Ferryzijl, can you make sure there are some records in table with timestamp 2019-11-18 via storage explorer?